# Is there a mechanism to unvote a close vote?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Many questions receive some close votes based on their original wording.  They are then reworded in a way that solves the closure issue or makes clear that they are not a duplicate.  However, the close votes remain, stigmatizing the question, and the question remains in the close queue, at some point to be unnecessarily presented for review.

Is there a mechanism where the person who voted for closure can unvote or retract the vote if they believe the question no longer has an issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. See [Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) for more info.

Just click on "close" again, and you will see a button for "retract close vote".

[image]